# Passing Array through Recursive Find and Replace Perl Script

Tags: arrays, perl, replace

I have a 'users-tb-deleted.txt' file which is a list of users, separated by a line break, who need to be removed from approximately 50 files in a directory structure.

How do I go about opening a large number of files and doing a find and replace using the previous list past into an array without writing 50 different file handle arguments that all do the same operation?

Current Code:

```
use File::Find;
open(FILE, "$path/delete-list.txt") || die "$!\n";
my @user = <FILE>;
close(FILE);
---
opendir(DIR, "/path/to/dir") || die "$!\n";
@docs= grep(/\.uid$/,readdir(DIR));    
foreach $file {
    open (RES, $file) || die "$!\n";
    while(<RES>){
        foreach $user (@user){
            chomp;
            s/$user//ig;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas, thoughts, suggestions?

Comment: What is a "previous list past"? In the sentence `doing a find and replace using the previous list past into an array`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just iterate through the files one by one to make your changes?

Comment: @TPL - The delete list being passed via array as shown in the code.

Jack - There are over 50 files to run this against.. It is an option but essentially I would write 50 file handles for the different files performing the same action. I am looking for a streamlined process where I can do both actions in one process.

Comment: @AndersonNicholasL - Ummm...why not just pick up the list of files that need changing, put them in an array, and loop through them? Unless we're talking about 100GB+ files, this really shouldn't be an issue. If this is going to be a one-off task, then there's no need to make things any fancier than necessary.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't actually use File::Find?

Comment: Are you referencing something similar to the following?

my $path = "/pat/to/dir/";
my $files = dirlist($path);

foreach my $fileInDirectory (@$files) {
        s/$user//ig($fileInDirectory);
}

Comment: @AndersonNicholasL Oh, I see. You think that because you have 50 files, you cannot loop over the file names and open the files dynamically?

Comment: Yes, I don't believe I have seen anything like that. Maybe a small sample?

Comment: @AndersonNicholasL You're already doing it. `foreach $file (@docs) { open (RES, $file) || die $!; ...` Although you could join the replace words into a regex and do them all at once, e.g. `chomp(@user); my $rx = join "|", map quotemeta, @user; while(<RES>) { chomp; s/$rx//ig; print; }`  I assume you also want to print the changes to file somehow.

Comment: Of course, you may be replacing partial matches, such as deleting `joe` from `billy-joe`. In which case a regex might be a poor choice, and `eq` would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use File::Find;
use Tie::File;

... # define $path and @dirs and &some_condition;

open(FILE, "$path/delete-list.txt") || die "$!\n";
my @user = <FILE>;
close(FILE); 
my $regex = join "|", @user;

find(\&wanted, @dirs);

sub wanted {
    my $full_path = $File::Find::name;
    next if -d $full_path;
    next unless &some_condition($full_path);

    tie my @lines, $full_path or die $!;

    for my $line (@lines) {
        $line =~ s/($regex)//ig;
    }

    untie @lines;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that

```
opendir(DIR, "/path/to/dir") || die "$!\n";
@docs= grep(/\.uid$/,readdir(DIR));
```

is much easier read as

```
@docs = glob( '/path/to/dir/*.uid' );
```

Comment: I chose not to include the less-popular old-style version for a reason.